# Fancybox iframe title link

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have a problem. I have a page http://www.hmaloha.com/bionutrient.php where when clicked over the play button, a video plays on fancybox iframe and a logo is at the top when the video loads. Now I need to add a link to that logo. I have been trying to alter the fancybox code but no luck. Any help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#malohaStory').click(function(){
                $.fancybox({
                    overlayOpacity: 1,
                    overlayColor: '#bbb',
                    padding : 0,
                    autoScale : false,
                    transitionIn : 'none',
                    transitionOut : 'none',
                    titleShow : true,
                    titlePosition : 'float', // 'float', 'outside', 'inside' or 'over'
                    titleFormat : function(){
                        return '&nbsp;';
                    },
                    type: 'iframe',
                    href: 'http://hmaloha.com/js/flowplayer/video/index.html',
                    height: 545,
                    width: 920,
                    swf : {
                        wmode : 'transparent',
                        allowfullscreen : 'true'
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });


        });
```

Comment: I guess you already got it sorted, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Within your `$.fancybox()` call, include the `beforeLoad` method as shown below, changing my example link with your `url`:

```
beforeLoad: function() {
  this.title = '<a href="http://www.example.com/link.html">' + this.title + '</a>';
}
```

So your final code (if you keep everything you have above, although I don't know what your `titleFormat` function is doing) would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#malohaStory').click(function(){
            $.fancybox({
                overlayOpacity: 1,
                overlayColor: '#bbb',
                padding : 0,
                autoScale : false,
                transitionIn : 'none',
                transitionOut : 'none',
                titleShow : true,
                titlePosition : 'float', // 'float', 'outside', 'inside' or 'over'
                titleFormat : function(){
                    return '&nbsp;';
                },
                type: 'iframe',
                href: 'http://hmaloha.com/js/flowplayer/video/index.html',
                height: 545,
                width: 920,
                swf : {
                    wmode : 'transparent',
                    allowfullscreen : 'true'
                }
                beforeLoad: function() {
                  this.title = '<a href="http://www.example.com/link.html">' + this.title + '</a>';
                }
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
```

Comment: I don't think that helps because `beforeLoad` is a fancybox **v2.x** callback but the OP is using **v1.3.4**. API options in v2.x are new and NOT compatible with previous versions.